# Calling an AlertDialog in another class

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to create a java class that holds all of the alerts for my application. I want to make the methods static so they are easier to call. Here is my code.

**Alert Class**

```
public class Alerts {

    // Player has not selected a team
    public static void noPlayerTeam(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view);
        builder.setMessage("Select your team.");
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        builder.setNeutralButton(
                "Okay",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog a = builder.create();
        a.show();
    }
}
```

**Acvitety code**

```
Alerts.noPlayerTeam(view);
```

The documentation shows `AlertDialog.Builder(Context context)`

I'm struggling with the getting the context of the activity to the Alert class. The error with the code above is *Error:(13, 63) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Context*.

I know the code works because I can execute it functionally in the same script as the activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `view.getContext()` instead of `view` :

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
```

Need to pass valid Context(*UI Context*) to Builder constructor to get `AlertDialog` instance.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I knew it was a simple fix, but couldn't figure it out! I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- put this in `Constant`

---

```
public static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String message)
    {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
          } 
        }); 
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

---

- call in your `Activity`

---

```
Constant.alertDialogShow(YourActivity.this,"Your Error Message");
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Common class for Alert**

```
public class Alert {
    // Alert with Message and ok
    public static void showAlertDialog(Context context,String title ,String msg){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }});
        builder.create().show();
    }
    // Alert with Message and ok Click Event
    public static void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title ,String msg, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) listener);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",(DialogInterface.OnClickListener) listener);
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

### **In Main Activity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Alert.showAlertDialog(this,"Testing","Demooo");

        Alert.showAlertDialog(this,"Testing","Demoooooo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which==DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                    //Your Code
                }else
                    {
                    //Your Code
                }

            }});
    }
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks